# How to set layout for topEmptyRegion in WearablListView?

Tags: listview, wear-os

[image: Android wear header title]

The "Disconnected" region is the top empty region thats scrolls up when this listview is scrolled. How do I set layout for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking at your example using the hierarchyviewer it is implemented like this:

A RelativeLayout holds the WearableListView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/llist"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your onCreate() method of the Activity add the header:

```
public class TestListViewActivity extends Activity implements WearableListView.ClickListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.llist);

    // Below is your header e.g. "disconnected"
    // You can do it in code, or you have already defined it in the above xml layout
    final TextView header = new TextView(this);
    header.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));

    final WearableListView listView = (WearableListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Add the header, or you have already defined it in the xml layout
    l.addView(header, 0);

    // Now comes the scrolling part (makes the header disappear)
    listView.addOnScrollListener(new WearableListView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScroll(int i) {}

        @Override
        public void onAbsoluteScrollChange(int i) {
            // Do only scroll the header up from the base position, not down...
            if (i > 0)
                header.setY(-i);
        }

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(int i) {}

        @Override
        public void onCentralPositionChanged(int i) {}
    });
```

To sum it up, you have a View above the WearableListView and when scrolling the ListView, you simply scroll the header out of sight.

Looking again at the original question, the anser is: There is no layout, that is provided and that you can change. You have to do it yourself.

Hope this helps.

**Edit 17.09.2014**:

If you want the header to scroll in from the top (as in the google example), add a file res/anim/slidein_top.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromYDelta="-100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />
</set>
```

and this code to your activity:

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
        RelativeLayout l = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.llist);
        final Animation slide = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.slidein_top);
        // find the header or cache it elsewhere
        l.getChildAt(0).startAnimation(slide);
    }
}
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is the variable "rk" that you are using in onAbsoluteScrollChangeListener?

Comment: Glad you liked it! rk is an artefact from my code :-) It should be the variable *header* (the TextEdit), which scrolls up.

Comment: Great!!! Got it working!!! Thanks a lot. Though I must mention that I could not get it working in Java (was getting NPE while adding header view to the RelativeLayout). Just declared the header in xml and everything is working perfectly now. Answer Accepted.

Answer (score 5):

For those of you still looking at this, I would like to build on boun's answer. `onAbsoluteScrollChange` is now deprecated and the code should be put into `onScroll`, instead.

However, the parameter of `onScroll` is the amount of change since the last time `onScroll` was called, where as the parameter of `onAbsoluteScrollChange` is the current position after the scroll; therefore, we must modify the code a little.

To work around the deprecated method, remove the code from `onAbsoluteScrollChange` and do the following:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(int i) {
    header.setY(header.getY() - i);
}
```

Comment: This solution works much much better than this based on `onAbsoluteScrollChange`

Answer (score 0):

I post the complete working and simple example.. check this out

Here is Layout File.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000" >



    <android.support.wearable.view.WearableListView
        android:id="@+id/wearable_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="35dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false" />



    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="49dp"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:background="#1E1E20">

        <TextView

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:id="@+id/header_text"
            android:layout_marginTop="9dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and Coding Part..

```
final RelativeLayout header = findViewById(R.id.header);

final TextView header_text =  findViewById(R.id.header_text);
header_text.setText("Configurations");

WearableListView wearableListView = findViewById(R.id.wearable_list_view);

wearableListView.addOnScrollListener(new WearableListView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScroll(int i) {
        header.setY(header.getY() - i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAbsoluteScrollChange(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(int i) {}

    @Override
    public void onCentralPositionChanged(int i) {}
});
```

Thats it. Here you can Change Header Text as your requirements. onScroll is working better than onAbsoluteScrollChange.