# WearableListView Header

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, wear-os

I am trying to create a `WearableListView` similar to the one in the default Settings app. I have a `WearableListView` that scrolls, and animates each element. All I need now is a header on top of the list that scrolls up when the list scrolls. This is the same behavior that the title 'Settings' has in the Settings app.

The only method I have found to do this, used here: [How to Set the Layout for topEmptyRegion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25837023/5115932), implements a `WearableListView.OnScrollListener()`. Then uses the `onAbsoluteScrollChange()` method to set the displacement of the `TextView` used as a header. But, according to the [Android Developer References](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/WearableListView.OnScrollListener.html), this method is deprecated. The documentation even states: BE ADVISED DO NOT USE THIS *This might provide wrong values when the contents of a RecyclerView change*.

I would like to know if anyone else has found a way to implement a header that behaves this way, one that is not deprecated. Possibly something that I missed in the Android Wear documentation?

**EDIT:**

I tried to implement this method anyway. As it turns out, `WearableListView.setOnScrollListener()` would not take a `new WearableListView.OnScrollListener()`. Instead it asked for its parent `RecyclerView.OnScrollListener`, which does not have a `onAbsoluteScrollChange()` method. It does have an `onScrolled()` method, which I tried to implement. As it turns out, this completely overrides the default scroll listener for `WearableListView` and makes it so the centered item can be off-center. Definitely not the effect I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since onScroll() is not deprecated, you may be able to accomplish the same by implementing that in your listener:

```
@Override
public void onScroll(int scroll) {
    header.setY(header.getY() - scroll);
}
```

where `header` is the header component.

**EDIT:** Make sure you use `WearableListView.addOnScrollListener` *not* `WearableListView.setOnScrollListener()`

Comment: I actually tried to implement something similar (I edited my question to reflect this), and it did not produce the results I was looking for.

Comment: You need to use WearableListView.addOnScrollListenet(WearableListView.OnScrollListener) and then override what I suggested in my solution and that should work.

Comment: Wow, I was using `setOnScrollListener()` instead of `addOnScrollListener()` I misread. That works perfectly, thank you. I hope you don't mind, I submitted an edit to your answer to reflect that.

Comment: Glad it worked; sure, submit an edit if you think it can make it more clear for others.